# ifthen condition fails for gitinfo2 metadata

Tags: ifthenelse, gitinfo

I am using the `gitinfo2` package (2.0.7) together with the `ifthen` package (v1.1c), both from TeXLive 2017, in order to include Git metadata in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[local]{gitinfo2}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
commit \gitAbbrevHash
\ifthenelse{\equal{\gitBranch}{master}}{}{ on branch \gitBranch}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\gitDirty}{}}{}{ with local changes}
\end{document}
```

The intention is that the name of the branch should be printed, but only if it is not the master branch. So for the example I would expect only "commit e78b91e". However, the result is "commit e78b91e on branch master".

In other words, the test for `\gitBranch` always evaluates to false (while the test for `\gitDirty` works correctly). What am I missing?

Here is the contents of the `gitHeadLocal.gin` file:

```
\usepackage[%
    shash={e78b91e},
    lhash={e78b91e0e8582d75273ad4f04bda5ae3c52055bd},
    authname={Abcd Efgh},
    authemail={abcd@example.org},
    authsdate={2018-02-19},
    authidate={2018-02-19 20:00:05 +0100},
    authudate={1519066805},
    commname={Abcd Efgh},
    commemail={abcd@example.org},
    commsdate={2018-02-19},
    commidate={2018-02-19 20:02:01 +0100},
    commudate={1519066921},
    refnames={ (HEAD -> master)},
    firsttagdescribe={e78b91e},
    reltag={e78b91e}
]{gitexinfo}
```

Comment: if you put `\show\gitBranch` before the ifthenelse, what does the log message say?

Comment: `> \gitBranch=\long macro:`  
`->\detokenize \expandafter {\bcut }.`  
`l.6 \show\gitBranch`

Answer (score 2):

If the package sets

```
 \gitBranch=\long macro: ->\detokenize \expandafter {\bcut }
```

Then you get the same issue that occurs if you try to test the current filename as `\jobname` the  characters are all catcode 12 (like punctuation) not catcode 11 (letters) however you can use the same `\detokenize` e-tex primitive to get a catcode 12 test string, test against `\detokenize{master}` rather than `master`.